# I can’t deploy Mattermost locally on a Kubernetes cluster using Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress, mattermost

**Summary in one sentence**

I want to deploy Mattermost locally on a Kubernetes cluster using Minikube. I'm using Minikube v1.23.2 and Kubernetes v1.22.2

**Steps to reproduce**

I used this tutorial and the Github documentation:

- https://mattermost.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-mattermost-on-kubernetes-in-just-a-few-minutes/
- https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-operator/tree/v1.15.0

1. To start minikube: `minikube start`
2. To start ingress; `minikube addons enable ingress`
3. In the Github documentation they state that you need to install Custom Resources by running: `kubectl apply -f ./config/crd/bases`
4. Afterwards I followed step 4 to 9 from the first tutorial I noted above (without step 8)

**Observed behavior**

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error in the mattermost-operator: `no matches for kind \"Ingress\" in version \"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1\`.

See below for mattermost-operator logs:

```yaml
time="2021-10-13T15:56:47Z" level=info msg="[opr] Go Version: go1.16.3"
time="2021-10-13T15:56:47Z" level=info msg="[opr] Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64"
time="2021-10-13T15:56:47Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.metrics] metrics server is starting to listen" addr="0.0.0.0:8383"
time="2021-10-13T15:56:47Z" level=info msg="[opr] Registering Components"
time="2021-10-13T15:56:47Z" level=info msg="[opr] Starting manager"
I1013 15:56:47.972667       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease mattermost-operator/b78a986e.mattermost.com...
time="2021-10-13T15:56:47Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager] starting metrics server" path=/metrics
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.events] Normal" message="mattermost-operator-74bc664c46-866xd_4b3f7a90-923b-4b0a-ab01-4a1ebe955088 became leader" object="{ConfigMap mattermost-operator b78a986e.mattermost.com c7462714-0cda-4e03-9765-a2e8599fdbcf v1 11389 }" reason=LeaderElection
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.events] Normal" message="mattermost-operator-74bc664c46-866xd_4b3f7a90-923b-4b0a-ab01-4a1ebe955088 became leader" object="{Lease mattermost-operator b78a986e.mattermost.com ffe4104b-efa9-42da-8d16-5a85766366e3 coordination.k8s.io/v1 11390 }" reason=LeaderElection
I1013 15:57:05.433562       1 leaderelection.go:253] successfully acquired lease mattermost-operator/b78a986e.mattermost.com
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermost] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=installation.mattermost.com reconciler kind=Mattermost source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermostrestoredb] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=MattermostRestoreDB source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.clusterinstallation] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=ClusterInstallation source="kind source: /, Kind="
E1013 15:57:05.460380       1 event.go:264] Server rejected event '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"b78a986e.mattermost.com.16ada23da3ddb598", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"mattermost-operator", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, InvolvedObject:v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"mattermost-operator", Name:"b78a986e.mattermost.com", UID:"c7462714-0cda-4e03-9765-a2e8599fdbcf", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"11389", FieldPath:""}, Reason:"LeaderElection", Message:"mattermost-operator-74bc664c46-866xd_4b3f7a90-923b-4b0a-ab01-4a1ebe955088 became leader", Source:v1.EventSource{Component:"mattermost-operator-74bc664c46-866xd_4b3f7a90-923b-4b0a-ab01-4a1ebe955088", Host:""}, FirstTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xc051de5459b4cb98, ext:17770579701, loc:(*time.Location)(0x2333fe0)}}, LastTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xc051de5459b4cb98, ext:17770579701, loc:(*time.Location)(0x2333fe0)}}, Count:1, Type:"Normal", EventTime:v1.MicroTime{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, Series:(*v1.EventSeries)(nil), Action:"", Related:(*v1.ObjectReference)(nil), ReportingController:"", ReportingInstance:""}': 'events is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:mattermost-operator:mattermost-operator" cannot create resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "mattermost-operator"' (will not retry!)
E1013 15:57:05.469732       1 event.go:264] Server rejected event '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"b78a986e.mattermost.com.16ada23da3fa25ac", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"mattermost-operator", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, InvolvedObject:v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Lease", Namespace:"mattermost-operator", Name:"b78a986e.mattermost.com", UID:"ffe4104b-efa9-42da-8d16-5a85766366e3", APIVersion:"coordination.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"11390", FieldPath:""}, Reason:"LeaderElection", Message:"mattermost-operator-74bc664c46-866xd_4b3f7a90-923b-4b0a-ab01-4a1ebe955088 became leader", Source:v1.EventSource{Component:"mattermost-operator-74bc664c46-866xd_4b3f7a90-923b-4b0a-ab01-4a1ebe955088", Host:""}, FirstTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xc051de5459d13bac, ext:17772215701, loc:(*time.Location)(0x2333fe0)}}, LastTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xc051de5459d13bac, ext:17772215701, loc:(*time.Location)(0x2333fe0)}}, Count:1, Type:"Normal", EventTime:v1.MicroTime{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, Series:(*v1.EventSeries)(nil), Action:"", Related:(*v1.ObjectReference)(nil), ReportingController:"", ReportingInstance:""}': 'events is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:mattermost-operator:mattermost-operator" cannot create resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "mattermost-operator"' (will not retry!)
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermost] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=installation.mattermost.com reconciler kind=Mattermost source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermostrestoredb] Starting Controller" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=MattermostRestoreDB
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.clusterinstallation] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=ClusterInstallation source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermost] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=installation.mattermost.com reconciler kind=Mattermost source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.clusterinstallation] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=ClusterInstallation source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermostrestoredb] Starting workers" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=MattermostRestoreDB worker count=1
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermost] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=installation.mattermost.com reconciler kind=Mattermost source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.clusterinstallation] Starting EventSource" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=ClusterInstallation source="kind source: /, Kind="
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=error msg="[opr.controller-runtime.source] if kind is a CRD, it should be installed before calling Start" error="no matches for kind \"Ingress\" in version \"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1\"" kind=Ingress.networking.k8s.io
time="2021-10-13T15:57:05Z" level=info msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager.controller.mattermostrestoredb] Stopping workers" reconciler group=mattermost.com reconciler kind=MattermostRestoreDB
I1013 15:57:07.096906       1 request.go:655] Throttling request took 1.0466297s, request: GET:https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/events.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
time="2021-10-13T15:57:07Z" level=error msg="[opr.controller-runtime.source] if kind is a CRD, it should be installed before calling Start" error="no matches for kind \"Ingress\" in version \"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1\"" kind=Ingress.networking.k8s.io
time="2021-10-13T15:57:07Z" level=error msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager] error received after stop sequence was engaged" error="no matches for kind \"Ingress\" in version \"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1\""
time="2021-10-13T15:57:07Z" level=error msg="[opr.controller-runtime.manager] error received after stop sequence was engaged" error="leader election lost"
time="2021-10-13T15:57:07Z" level=error msg="[opr] Problem running manager" error="no matches for kind \"Ingress\" in version \"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1\""
```

Really tried many variations of implementations and changed the yml files but nothing seems to work. Anybody an idea?

Comment: What version of Minikube and Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: Minikube v1.23.2 and Kubernetes v1.22.2 @clarj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` is deprecated as of Kubernetes v1.22, according to this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122), which is a problem if Mattermost installation defines and uses v1beta1 configurations.

Short of trying to change the existing Mattermost installation configuration, you may have more luck downgrading Minikube to v1.21.5.

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.21.5
```

Comment: Yes another person in the community from Mattermost noted that the Mattermost operator does not yet support Kubernets v1.22+, so I'm going to try this tomorrow. I'll keep you updated

Comment: This solution fixed the particular problem I was facing. Got another error now though lol